# Git for Windows: move [winUpdater] section out of .gitconfig

Tags: git-config, dotfiles, git-for-windows

I share my dotfiles across multiple systems via a git repository, that includes the global .gitconfig file.

Now I want to export those files to a Windows system as well and use them in a git-bash environment. I've noticed that my current .gitconfig contains the [winUpdater] section. I assume its content is updated regularly and automatically, so I'll need to take care not to push those changes to my common repository.

It's possible to hide my shared .gitconfig file in an include directive and leave global .gitconfig almost empty but it's not very convenient either.

I wonder if there's a way to configure the winUpdater to use a different file for version tracking.

```
$ cat .gitconfig
[winUpdater]
        recentlySeenVersion = 2.24.1.windows.2
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe unticking "Check daily for Git for Windows updates" when you install Git for Windows solves the problem.

Comment: Well, not quite. I still want auto-updates, but not the garbage in my .gitconfig which I always assumed to be a personal thing :)

BTW, I did look through the code of the update-script and it seems that usage of the system-wide .gitconfig is pretty much hard-coded at this point.